# How to use my custom normal.dot or normal.dotm in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

How to use my custom normal.dot or normal.dotm in Word 2010?

I have my template file. How to use it for blank documents?

Note: I don't want to "save" some settings into current template, I want to USE already existing settings.

Comment: You should be able to simply open the template to be able to create files based on that template. Or are you asking how  to make ALL new Word documents based on that template?

Comment: Yes all new documents from my existing custom template

Comment: Is the normal.dotm file in your "Personal" templates folder or in the main templates folder?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your template file in Word
2. Right Click on "Normal" (this should be on the "Home" ribbon under
   "Styles")
3. Choose "Modify..."
4. You can adjust the basic formatting style with the tools on that
   main screen, or you can select the "Format" drop-down/combo box in
   the lower left corner.
5. Once you have modified the style, be sure to fill in the circle (aka
   radio button) in front of "New documents based on this template"
6. Click "OK"

If you close out of Word 2010 and reopen the program, you should see the changes that you made to the blank template.

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/cannot-change-the-default-template-normaldotx-in/ca261e8d-4af7-4d25-a894-9c2c4351c48a) based on Word 2010.

Comment: Will this ensure, that any new changes to the styles will be stored in that `DOT` or `DOTM` file I used? Or may be it will store styles somewhere it likes? I need to use my specific template, in full sense. Not copy it somewhere.

Comment: I guess not. I guess you suggested a trick to copy my template to global template file. I need not that.

Comment: It's not a trick. It's built in functionality of Word. The way I understood your question is the how I approached this answer. If it did not work as you expected, please give constructive feedback with details in order for someone to help you.

Comment: I just want to `use` my template file in full sense. `use` means use both for reading and writing.

Comment: Templates are not used for reading unless the file was created with that specific template. When you open a Word file created from a different template, it is in the format it was saved in. Here is a great reference to [Learn about templates in Office 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/learn-about-templates-in-office-2010-HA101976901.aspx)

Comment: I know template is readed when file is creating on it. Don't say trivia.